# Scanline C++ function not taking input?

Tags: c++, input, inputstream

My program is freezing once it gets to the getline() function, regardless of what I input (when pressing enter).

Are there any ways to fix this usage of getline or is there any alternative input streams in C/C++ that I could implement?

Example input: query 20130105 string1 string2

```
puts("a");
string line;
getline(cin, line);
puts("b");

string words[4] = {"", "", "", ""};
int wordCount = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < line.length(); i++) {
   puts("c");
   string currentsub = line.substr(i-1, i);
   if(currentsub != "\t")
      words[wordCount] += currentsub;
   else
      wordCount++;
}
```

Comment: You mean the call to `getline()` itself doesn't return, or the code your using to parse the line is getting hung up?

Comment: @TrippKinetics Essentially getline() is taking infinite input

Comment: Are you saying that something like `int main() { string line; getline(cin, line); cout << line; }` hangs and doesn't print anything when you run it?

Comment: `while(line.substr(i-1, i) != "\t") { words[wordCount] += line.substr(i-1, i);}` This loop will run until the string consumes all available memory (whereupon the program will crash, but you'd have to wait a while for that). You keep checking and appending `line[0]` over and over.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I hadn't even realised that. I just added three print statements. The program will only print 'a' but any code after getline() isn't processed, regardless of what I input.

Comment: In that case, the `getline` call likely waits for input. The input you think you've provided to it has likely been previously consumed elsewhere, in the code you haven't shown. I, for one, find it difficult to reason about code I cannot see; if you are interested in further discussion, prepare and show a [mcve].

Comment: Are you running your program in Qt-creator? I was able to replicate your problem in qt-creator. But, it works fine on the terminal.

Comment: @TusharNakini I was compiling with Linux MinGW, I think the problem was runtime issues in the code preceding the inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped. It turns out there were a number of runtime and memory management issues in the code preceding it, even though they were not outputted to the console. The scanner ended up behaving very randomly, sometimes working and sometimes not under the exact same procedures... I'm a noob in C++ and StackOverflow. That will change with time.